# ARRAYFORMULA is only populating the first row

Tags: google-sheets, split, pivot, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have financial data that I am trying to summarize in a format that can be used by a line chart.

The example spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ryz09dCVQV7Cu0iYeHMVpqav_n4-TTqQbV1uTq1IXGo/edit?usp=sharing).

In my source data on the left, I have an entry per *Date*, *Symbol*, *Account*. I need to transform this data so there is a row per *Date* and a column for each *Symbol*. I will **SUM** *Total Value* regardless of account.

I found a way to pull a unique *Date* (see H2), and then transpose unique *Symbols* into columns (see I1).

I also found a way to use **SUMIFS** to get the aggregation I want (take a look at cell I2), but I can't figure out how to use **ARRAYFORMULA** to apply this value to all rows in column I.

I know I can drag my formula from I2 down to I3,I4,I.. etc, but this sheet is part of a larger project so I'd like it to auto-populate as dates are added to H.

From what I've read **ARRAYFORMULA** should apply the formula to multiple rows. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(A1:F, "select A,sum(F) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: @lvicks `Query` function is the first thing to consider.

Comment: This is the cleanest, I was playing with queries before but didn't realize I could use PIVOT. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Use formulas like this**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H="",,SUMIFS($F$2:$F, $A$2:$A, $H2, $B$2:$B, I$1)))
```

Add `IF(H2:H="",,`

***Explanation*** 
if the range is empty `""` do nothing `,,` else `Your formula`

### Your Example

| Cells | Formulas |
| --- | --- |
| I2 | `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H="",,SUMIFS($F$2:$F, $A$2:$A, $H2:H, $B$2:$B, I$1)))` |
| J2 | `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H="",,SUMIFS($F$2:$F, $A$2:$A, $H2:H, $B$2:$B, J$1)))` |
| K2 | `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H="",,SUMIFS($F$2:$F, $A$2:$A, $H2:H, $B$2:$B, K$1)))` |